# Complexity Analysis in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Can you guys help me determine the complexity of the following implementations of algorithms to add, multiply and transpose n X n matrices:
Thanks so much !!

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for( j = 0; j < n; j++)
      a[i][j] = b[i][j] + c[i][j];


for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
   for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
      for(k = a[i][j] = 0; k < n; k++)
         a[i][j] += b[i][k] * c[k][j]; 


for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
   for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++){
      tmp = a[i][j];
      a[i][j] = a[j][i];
      a[j][i] = tmp;
```

}

Comment: What problems do you encounter while trying to determine the complexity yourself?

Comment: Recommendation: State what you believe the answer to be and your reasoning, then ask if you're right. You might be right and the answer's a really simple, "Yes." If not, this gives us a baseline to form answers around and allows us to target mistakes and show you how to not make them in the future. In addition never discount the social importance of showing your work.

Comment: `O(n²) + O(n³) +  O(n²)` is `O(n³)`

Answer (score 0):

If you nest loops inside each other the complexity will be the lengths (times of exechution) multiplied.

So when you have 2 loops(add,transpose) with length n the complex will be `O(n*n)=O(N^2)` and when you have 3 it will be `O(n*n*n)=O(n^3)`